# Get Datetime of Last Schema Change of BQ Table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been trying to figure out the datetime of the last update to a table's schema in BQ - I had imagined the info would be in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, but it's not. I also looked into getting a TableReference object from the REST API which has LastModifiedTime - but LastModifiedTime includes changes to the data in the table, not just updates to the schema.

Where can the last update time of a table definition be found?